# angular foreach not waiting for server response

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.forEach(tableName, function(value, key){  
 console.log("value ", value)
 getFormsService.getTableData(value).then(function(dynResponse){
  console.log("key",key," dynResponse", dynResponse.data)
            });
});
```

In above code **tableName**  contains table names array
ex: tableName=["table1","table2","table3","tale4"]

each table with 50, 10, 5, 20 records

My output:

```
    "value ", table1
    "value ", table2
    "value ", table3
    "value ", table4

    "key",2," dynResponse", array(5 records)
    "key",1," dynResponse", array(10 records)
    "key",3," dynResponse", array(20 records)
    "key",0," dynResponse", array(50 records)
```

Expected output :

```
"value ", table1
"key",0," dynResponse", array(50 records)
"value ", table2
"key",1," dynResponse", array(10 records)
"value ", table3
"key",2," dynResponse", array(5 records)
"value ", table4
"key",3," dynResponse", array(20 records)


help me to get expected output

Thanks
```

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach(tableName, function(value, key){  
   getFormsService.getTableData(value).then(function(dynResponse){
      console.log("value ", value)
      console.log("key",key," dynResponse", dynResponse.data)
   });
});
```

I am not sure, what you want to do exactly. For executing the service request synchronously you may use `all()` method of `$q` service.

Answer (score -1):

Here  `getFormsService.getTableData` callback is an asynchronous  call .  Thus the loop thread and service thread are not chained together  rather its another thread all together.

```
// this line does not wait for service callback to be completed.
angular.forEach(tableName, function(value, key){  

  // this is an a asynchronous call 
 getFormsService.getTableData(value).then(function(dynResponse){
  console.log("key",key," dynResponse", dynResponse.data)
            });
});
```

You can change the service to make one call or use something like this

```
  var inUse=false;
  angular.forEach(tableName, function(value, key){  

     while (!inUse) {
         //waiting call might be costly you can try wait here as well
      }

     inUse=true;
      // this is an a asynchronous call 
     getFormsService.getTableData(value).then(function(dynResponse){
                 console.log("key",key," dynResponse", dynResponse.data)
                 inUse=false;
                });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is always synchronous and single-threaded. Since you are calling a service code will not wait till get the response. it will execute rest of the code and when the response received it execute the rest of the code.

JavaScript is only asynchronous in the sense that it can make, for example, Ajax calls. The code will stop executing until the call returns (successfully or otherwise), at which point the callback will run synchronously.

```
function FirstFunction(callback) {
    angular.forEach(tableName, function(value, key){  
       console.log("value ", value);
    });
    callback();
}

FirstFunction(function() {
    getFormsService.getTableData(value).then(function(dynResponse){
         console.log("key",key," dynResponse", dynResponse.data)
    });
});
```